# How to upload multiple images from angular 8 to asp .net core

Tags: angular, .net-core

I was searching for a solution in the past day about this but never found a solution...

I am sending multiple images from angular using **from data** and if i check the network for the api call the files are sended but when i check the parameters on the api method it shows count=0

**Angular Code**

```
createProduct(product: any, images: File[]) {
// return this.http.post(this.createProductUrl, product).pipe(
  // switchMap((resp: Product) => {

    const colorId = '2';
    const productId = '3';
    const image = new FormData();

    for (let index = 0; index < images.length; index++) {
      image.append('files', images[index]);
    }


    return this.http.post(`${this.createImagesForProduct}/${productId}/color/${colorId}`, image)
    .pipe(map(
      resp => {
        return console.log(resp);
      }
    ));
```

[Back End Method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o1LIC.png)

[Google DevTools Network Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vibtb.png)

please i need your help

Comment: In your controller action, is `Request.Form.Files` empty as well?

Comment: okk, i tried  `Request.Form.Files` and its working but is there a way that i can achive that using fromform?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert your request body into model

```
public class Model{
  public int productId{get;set;}
  public int colorId{get;set;}
  public List<IFormFile> files{get;set;}
}
```

in request write

```
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateImage(Model param){}
```

in angular put all elements into formdata

```
    const image = new FormData();
    image.append('productId',`${productId}`);
    image.append('colorId',`${colorId}`);
    for (let index = 0; index < images.length; index++) {
        image.append('files', images[index]);
    }
    return this.http.post(`${this.createImagesForProduct}`, image)
        .pipe(map(
          resp => {
            return console.log(resp);
          }
        ));
```