# Upload Multiple Image From Angular To Laravel

Tags: angular, laravel, api, angular11

I cannot upload multiple images from **angular ** using a Laravel api, when I try to upload these images from Postman it works, but when I do it from my frontend it failed.

I need a help please , any idea !!

this is my api function :

```
public function storeImages(Request $request) 
{           
    if($request->hasFile('images')) {
        $data = [];
                    
        foreach($request->file('images') as $image)
        {
            $Imagename = $image->getClientOriginalName();
            $image->move(public_path('/images'), $Imagename);   
            $data[] = $Imagename;                            
        }
         
        $file = new ImageAnnonce($request->input()) ;
        $file->annonceId = $request->annonceId;
        $file->image_name = json_encode($data);
        $file->save();

        return response()->json($data); 
    }
    else {
        return response()->json(['message' => 'failed']);  
    }
}
```

This is the html

```
<form (ngSubmit)="saveMultipleImage()">
  <input
    class="form-control"
    type="file"
    id="images"
    name="images[]"
    (change)="onSelectFile($event)"
    multiple
  />
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary float-right" id="publier-btn">
    submite
  </button>
</form>
```

file.ts

```
saveMultipleImage(){   
    const headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data');
    headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');

   var formdata = new FormData();
   //formdata.append('annonceId', '2' );
   for (let i = 0; i < this.length; i++) 
   {
       formdata.append('images', this.docs[i].name );
       //console.log('name -->', this.docs[i].name );
   }

   this.http.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/storeImages', formdata,{headers: headers}).subscribe(res =>  {
       console.log(res);
   });
}
```

```
      docs:any;
      length:any;

      onSelectFile(event)
      { 
        this.docs = <File>event.target.files;
        this.length = <File>event.target.files.length;
      }
```

It returns always

```
{message: "failed"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try by removing headers.append('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data'); from your header? Also, is your console log giving you the correct logs?

Lastly, what's the datatype of docs variable? Try making it of type File

```
docs: File[] = [];
```

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of the Postman making this request? I want to see body of your request that goes from postman. - Something like this - https://snipboard.io/9JLmKj.jpg

Comment: yaa of course ,  [link](https://snipboard.io/yZEOI8.jpg) , and sorry for the delay

Comment: this is the error when I remove the condition if(if($request->hasFile('images'))) ----------> error:  message: "foreach() argument must be of type array|object, null given"

Comment: In Angular, you are appending the name of the image and not the image. Check the Angular code on this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61815627/how-to-upload-multiple-images-from-angular-8-to-asp-net-core and let me know if it worked.

Comment: I tried that soution  but no result , I think the broblem is coming from the backend side . anyway I'm so thankful sir :)

Comment: There's no problem in the backend if it's working fine in postman. Can you inspect the network tab while making the request from Angular and see if the data is going correctly? Can I get those screenshots? Also, is it possible to share the entire Angular code? A snapshot will do. Just hide proprietary and sensitive information.

Comment: of course : [onSelectMethod](https://snipboard.io/ULDSYQ.jpg) , [saveMultipleImage()](https://snipboard.io/2iT8vQ.jpg) , [htmlCode](https://snipboard.io/iyv8m3.jpg) ,[response](https://snipboard.io/g1EDZ0.jpg) [network](https://snipboard.io/zLqEkG.jpg)   ---->>>   I tried this for name attribute but still not working  : <input type="file" name="images[]"  (change)="onSelectFile($event)" multiple>

Comment: Just one thing. In your SaveMultiple image, you are `this.length;` in forloop. Can you try with `this.docs.length;`?

Comment: I did, still same error -> : foreach() argument must be of type array|object, null given

Comment: Finally the problem is solved by changing one line in api function [api function](https://snipboard.io/a1Rtjg.jpg) , Thanks for your suggestions and support . :D